# Temporary - unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, spring-boot, shopify, shopify-app, handshake

We are making graphQL call from a spring application. We are getting this following certificate exception.

We make this call for different set of Shopify users we manage (each one identified by a shop id). The domain on graphQL call will change per user (i.e., we will have the shop id on URL). We are getting this following certificate exception for certain shops (certain domains). But the certificate is common for all the domain. After some time, this exception stops happening for the same domain for which we faced this issue.

sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

If it was something permanent, I could have updated the certificate info to java. But this is happening only for certain calls and for certain period of time. Then it starts working fine for the failed domain there after.

Comment: Isn't this always happening for the same set of users? Are there otherwise maybe separate severs that are not all running in the same configuration?

Comment: Yes I assumed the same. It happens for the some set of users for certain period of time and then it won't happen. I can check one more thing if this user is new in our system and this is happening at the beginning. I was asked to add loggers to capture the handshake failure. I read about enabling ssl logs with a VM option. Can you recommend one, so that it won't generate lot of logs and provides the required info to debug this issue.

Answer (score 1):

We added alerts in our system to try the domain in local as soon as this failure happens. Then we replicated the issue in postman and also by writing a piece of code to reproduce the java network call and checked the logs. On postman, we got the response of redirection.

openDNS was deployed in our organization as an additional layer of security for our network. As mentioned in my issue description, part of the domain changes per user. openDNS considers certain domains as a threat if it doesn't find it in trusted domains as per its policy and was blocked for 48 hours. openDNS was responding with a blocked message from openDNS server and it will have openDNS certificate which was not there in java resulting in certificate exception.

So, we see this failure only for 48hours and then it was allowed by openDNS.

Part of the domain which doesn't change is configured on openDNS to trust the domain to resolve this issue.